# How to print pdf file using wifi printer in iphone

Tags: iphone, printing

Please bare if is repeated question...

In my application there is a pdf file and i have to print it using print button through i-phone.

I search lot but didnt find. There the provide a Print n Share software for such thing but it do not suit to my requirement.

I need core programming coding support for printing it.

Is there any sample application which have wifi printer enabled feature.

Please tell me any sample application which help me to connect to wifi printer for print through printer or suggest any recommended site or code to refer.

There is no support in the iphone api also.. I am new to this please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hello friend. did you get the answer for your question. me too take print pdf file from iphone app. how to do this. any sample codes. can you help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I would imagine that you would need the printer driver installed on the phone. That would, of course, allow you to print from that specific printer but what if you wanted to print from any arbitrary printer? Loading a bunch of arbitrary drivers would be lots of overhead and there could also be licensing issues involved. If there were a generic wifi print standard that vendors could/would adopt then maybe...?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about iPhone programming but I can say that more and more printers are supporting direct PDF printing which means that if you can get the file to the printer it would simply print.  This doesn't allow for paper tray select etc. but could work.  Keep in mind that this isn't the best option for the home as direct PDF printing is typically only supported on workgroup/network printers and not always found on devices that you'd find in the home.  If you could get a PDF to Postscript converter installed this might do the trick but I'm guessing running something like Ghostscript on an iPhone isn't really feasible!

Answer (score 0):

There is new support for wireless printing in iOS 4.2.